# How to extract a text summary from a wikipedia term entry in html tags?

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

[image]

In the attached html screenshot, I want to get the text summary  in the 'lemma-summary' section. It's usually the first sentence of a wikipedia entry. This is a Chinese wikipedia entry. I used this code through BeautifulSoup

```
summaries = doc.getElements('div', attr='label-module', value='para').text
```

But this returns all text sections of the html page without using the 'lemma-summary'. If I do this:

```
summary = soup.select(".lemma-summary")
```

This does gives the right section (only the summary section), but it returns a ResultSet object, and I don't know how to get down to the exact text part.

How to extract the text part from this tag?

The URL of the page is here:

```
https://baike.baidu.com/item/tt%E8%AF%AD%E9%9F%B3
```

I want to extract this summary text:

```
"ika是深圳缇卡基因美容生物科技有限公司的一个化妆品品牌。"
```

Comment: Please do not post images as code. instead, edit your question with the HTML. What is the URL?

Comment: What is `doc.getElements`?

Comment: @MendelG, please see my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use selenium to get the page to load. If you can get the right html without selenium that work too.

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")


driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://baike.baidu.com/item/tt%E8%AF%AD%E9%9F%B3'
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
```

This

```
soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'para', 'label-module': 'para'}).text
```

gets you

```
'TT语音App，提供游戏组队开黑、职业电竞培养、达人娱乐互动等游戏社交场景。\n[1]\xa0\n'
```

and this

```
summary = soup.select(".lemma-summary")
for s in summary:
    print(s.text)
```

gets you

```
TT语音App，提供游戏组队开黑、职业电竞培养、达人娱乐互动等游戏社交场景。
[1]
```

Comment: Could there be multiple "lemma-summary" tags in the same html?

Comment: Yes. I’m not an expert on html but I think id attributes  are supposed to be unique, others not sure.